# In beta SEs, proposing tag synonyms requires 1k rep, not 2.5k

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, privileges

Compare [the comment here](https://askubuntu.com/tags/10.04/synonyms):

> Users with more than **1000** reputation can suggest and vote on tag synonyms.

...and the privileges page here:

> **2500**  Suggest and vote on tag synonyms

Some of the obscure rep-based privileges may have the same problem, but this was particularly glaring because it apparently ranked *above* the 10k tools.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66866/math-sx-has-the-750-rep-threshold-for-closing-privilege-ive-got-the-power-at-re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed, a UI bug, fixed in dev will be deployed soonish.