# math.sx FAQ says 750 needed for closing privilege, I've got the power at rep. 743

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, vote-to-close, privileges

Surely a bug?  I got the `Congrats, you've gained the privilege to cast close and reopen votes` message after being upvoted from rep. 733 to 743 an hour ago.

[User profile #100 on math.sx](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/100/charles-stewart), a.k.a. yours truly.

Possibly related: [In beta SEs, proposing tag synonyms requires 1k rep, not 2.5k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66783/in-beta-ses-proposing-tag-synonyms-requires-1k-rep-not-2-5k)

**Postscript** [The privileges page](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges) says that only 500 rep. is needed for this.  So it's a matter of the FAQ being wrong, I assume.

Answer (score 3):

The list on https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges is golden, it pulls out all its numbers from the same variables that are used for the actual reputation checks.

The FAQ uses the exact same variable we use in the privilege page.

There is a maximum 6 hour delay every time we touch rep requirements (which only developers can do). Developers have a page to override if needed and flush our cache.

Additionally, when you are really close to a threshold somebody could trigger you over it and then revert their vote, this is not something we will fix.

Comment: No, the [tag synonym one is definitely wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66783/in-beta-ses-proposing-tag-synonyms-requires-1k-rep-not-2-5k).

Comment: @radp we changed this today. I need to update the copies on the site. The priv page is right

Comment: *pull out all mentions of ... thresholds from the FAQ in favor of a link to the privileges page* - Yes, or autogenerate that part of the FAQ.