# Required reputation help text for tag synonyms is wrong on beta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, help-center

The page for the [create tag synonyms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) privileges, it states that:

> #### How do I propose or vote on tag synonyms?
>
> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can **vote** for tag synonyms.

But this privilege is awarded at 1250 reputation.

Comment: Not a duplicate of [In beta SEs, proposing tag synonyms requires 1k rep, not 2.5k](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66783/in-beta-ses-proposing-tag-synonyms-requires-1k-rep-not-2-5k?rq=1)

Comment: Beta sites have different threshold on many privileges. When out of beta the privilege will be gained at 2,500 rep.

Comment: And the help pages are shared across the network.

Comment: Sounds like they should be adjusted for beta sites!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) — I [edited the page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66736/revisions) on MSO¹, and it will be propagated across the network.

In general those pages should refer to other privileges by name, never by reputation, since the reputation thresholds differ between sites. When you need to refer to another privilege, you can link to it on MSO; the link will automatically be converted to the target site upon propagation.

¹  <sub>Anyone with 2000 reputation on Meta Stack Overflow can edit the privilege descriptions under https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges.</sub>

Comment: Whoa! I didn't realise we could actually edit those pages. Thanks for writing about that! \o/