# Please mention in the help screen that bounties require 75 rep

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, bounties, help-center

One user asked me how he could place a bounty on a question, and I was going to answer that he should look in the help screen. But then I noticed that [the bounty help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) doesn't say the minimum rep for putting a bounty is 75. This user had more than 50, but less than 75, so naturally he was confused.

Of course there are other pages that do mention the minimum rep needed for starting bounties, but not on the "What is a bounty? How can I start one?" page itself. The page title sounds specific enough to warrant such a mention. It's only one sentence.

Comment: There's probably lots of duplication between that page and [the bounty privilege page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) (which should be eliminated).

Comment: Well, the "attach it to any question as a bounty" is link to the privilege page which clearly says 75 points are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does already:

> Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation, and [attach it to *any* question as a bounty](/privileges/set-bounties).

Follow that link. It clearly states that 75 reputation is required.

Comment: OK, OK, and the "Privileges" link on the same page also states the 75 rep. I give in.

Answer (score 6):

Well this would apply to any privilege on the site. For instance, the help page about voting doesn't mention that you need 15 rep to vote up and 125 to vote down.

The help center explains what a functionality of the site is, regardless of when the privilege to use it is gained. The help center explains also how [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) affects the privileges.

> the more reputation you earn, the more privileges you gain.

So I think we've got that covered.

Most actions you can take on SO are enabled by a minimum level of reputation, so explicitly stating this in every help page would be redundant, I think.

Comment: You've got a point. However, in the case of bounties, it's not just a privilege, it is about rep itself. You can give up 50 points of your own hard-earned reputation, as the page says. So I think a quirk remark about needing 75 (rather than 51) wouldn't do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm strongly against mentioning the required reputation in privilege pages.

[The content of privilege description pages are shared across the entire network, so the beta sites have the same description as all other sites.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195882/required-reputation-help-text-for-tag-synonyms-is-wrong-on-beta-sites)

For the bounty privilege, it looks like it is 75 rep on ALL sites, including beta sites.

If you really feel that you need to duplicate this information, you could do that [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges)<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>* requires 2000 rep on Meta.SO</sup>